# Catching errors using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am attempting to write a .htaccess file to direct to and send index with an error code. Example index.php?error404 or index.php?error501.

I can direct an error within the root directory using the code below.

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 501 index.php?error=501
```

Example http://www.domain.com/file_does_not_exist.php and this works.
Result http://www.domain.com/index.php?error=404

The problem is catching and sending to index.php errors from sub directories.

Example http://www.domain.com/directory_does_not_exist Or
http://www.domain.com/directory_and/file_does_not_exist.php.

The result is http://www.domain.com/directory_does_not_exist/index.php?error=404 and therefore the CSS for the index.php in broken.

I have attempted the code below with no success. I am trying to redirect back to the index.php by rewriting the URL.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^err[45][0-9][0-9]$
RewriteRule ^\/.\/\.php$ /index.php?s=$1 [R]

AND

RewriteCond $1 !^err[45][0-9][0-9]$
RewriteRule ^([/]?*)\.php$ /index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use rewriting; just use absolute urls in your [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) directives (begin them with a `/`):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
ErrorDocument 501 /index.php?error=501
```

[The docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) show absolute urls in the examples:

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve. Alternatively, a message can be provided to be displayed by the browser. Examples::
>
> ```
> ErrorDocument 500 http://foo.example.com/cgi-bin/tester
> ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/bad_urls.pl
> ErrorDocument 401 /subscription_info.html
> ErrorDocument 403 "Sorry can't allow you access today"
> ```